# reference to view controller that is currently being shown in TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, reference

I'm building app with four view controllers lined-up in a TabBarController. I need to get a reference to the viewcontroller that is currently being shown to be able to do a switch statement in appdelegate. I mean I want to do something like: if ViewController1 is show do something, if ViewController2 is shown do something else, ....

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

What is really the question here?

The tab bar object will tell you which controller is currently displayed. For that use its property `selectedViewController`. Details here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedViewController

If you struggle accessing the tab bar controller itself, ... 
There is no function/method etc available to doing so. It is a common pattern to keep a reference to the tabbarcontoller object in your app delegate. 
This reference is typically set in `applicationDidLoadWithOptions`, where the tab bar is either loaded alreay from a storyboard or where you would load and display it when you do that programmatically.

There is a well documented way of accessing the delegate. That is:

```
MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

Then you go from there, access the tabbar and fetch the controller which is currently selected. (That itself may be a stack of view controllers if the selected view controller is root of a navigation controller stack. But that depends on how your app is build from there on.)

Comment: The thing is, I'm trying to display an email form from appdelegate, but I need to know first which viewcontroller is currently being displayed to be able to call the mail method in the current one. Understand now?

Comment: Yes I understand. And the problem is? Get your tab view controller and receive the selected view controller from it.

Comment: How can I do it? how can I specify in the appdelegate?

Comment: Do you storyboard or do you instanciate your tab bar controller programatically in your application delegate? Please show your applicationDidLaunchWithOptions.

Comment: it's empty. just returning 'YES'. I'm not sure I understand your advice. Could you please provide some code sample?